# Timing of ImageGrab.grab() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I want to take screenshot of my computer. So I use ImageGrab.grab() function.

But, when I take screenshot, the timing was little bit fast than what I want.
As you can see in below picture I use print() function before and after.

[image: Total code of .py file]

But the result dosen't show any of those like below.

[image: result of my screenshot]

How can I get the right timing?
Thanks for your help!!

And I use python 3.6

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    print("want to capture this text")
    image = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 1920, 1080)))
    print("don't want to capture this text")

    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post your code as text

Comment: I added my code as text!

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush the print statement like this:

```py
print("I want to see this", flush=True)
```

The output of the print statements are not printed out immediately. The flush should force it to be written out before continuing.

Comment: It dosen't solve my problem.. Thanks for you answer anyway!